# Use WP_Filesystem to list files in directory

Tags: uploads, wp-filesystem

Is there a way to list files in a directory using WP_filesystem instead of something like:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('Main Dir');
```

I want to list all the files and folders in my uploads folder so I was writing something like:

```
class ff
{
    public static function listFolderFiles($dir)
    {
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($ffs as $ff){
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
                echo '<li>'.$ff;
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
}
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
return New ff::listFolderFiles($upload_dir['basedir']);
```

but wanted to see if there is a better way..

Comment: Alternative from using `WP_Filesystem_Base` class, you can use [`list_files()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/list_files/) function. Please note that this function will be **always** removed files and folders that begins with **.** dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the documentation about the [Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) is very basic. What you are looking for is the `dirlist` method/function of the `WP_Filesystem_$method` class(es). The only documentation about it is the [docblock](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php#L787) out of the [`WP_Filesystem_Base`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php) class:

```
/**
 * Get details for files in a directory or a specific file.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param string $path Path to directory or file.
 * @param bool $include_hidden Optional. Whether to include details of hidden ("." prefixed) files.
 *                             Default true.
 * @param bool $recursive Optional. Whether to recursively include file details in nested directories.
 *                        Default false.
 * @return array|bool {
 *     Array of files. False if unable to list directory contents.
 *
 *     @type string 'name' Name of the file/directory.
 *     @type string 'perms' *nix representation of permissions.
 *     @type int 'permsn' Octal representation of permissions.
 *     @type string 'owner' Owner name or ID.
 *     @type int 'size' Size of file in bytes.
 *     @type int 'lastmodunix' Last modified unix timestamp.
 *     @type mixed 'lastmod' Last modified month (3 letter) and day (without leading 0).
 *     @type int 'time' Last modified time.
 *     @type string 'type' Type of resource. 'f' for file, 'd' for directory.
 *     @type mixed 'files' If a directory and $recursive is true, contains another array of files.
 * }
 */
 public function dirlist( $path, $include_hidden = true, $recursive = false ) {
     return false;
 }
```

In the base class the method doesn't actually have the functionality, for that take a look - for example - into the method declaration of [`dirlist`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php#L330) inside the [`WP_Filesystem_Direct`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php) class.

Now lets get to how to use it, a basic example would look like this:

```
global $wp_filesystem;
$filelist = $wp_filesystem->dirlist( '/the/path/to/the/files/' );
```

Comment: This worked reallny nice: http://www.stevenmcmillan.co.uk/blog/2011/recursive-folder-scan-using-recursivedirectoryiterator/  I will look into the way you described Thanks so much!

Comment: My pleasure! Sure you can do it with pure PHP, but than it wouldn't be based on the WP Filesystem, right? ;) @Rizzo

Comment: WordPress now has a bit more documentation on this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API
Updated your splendid answer to reflect this

Comment: In case that it is showing call to `dirlist()` on `null`, you have to call this function `WP_Filesystem();` before using `$wp_filesystem`. ;-)